# How to register dbus object using dbus-java?

Tags: java, linux, dbus

I'm trying to register object on dbus using dbus-java from org.freedesktop. According to [documentation](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/) such operation requires: creating DBusConnection, creating object and calling method exportObject on DBusConnection.

My Code:

```
DatabaseAccessImpl dbAccess = new DatabaseAccessImpl();

    System.out.println("Object created.");



    System.out.println("Trying to connect session bus");
    try {
        conn = DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.SESSION);
    } catch(DBusException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Connected to session bus.");

    System.out.println("Trying to register dbus object");

    try {
        conn.exportObject("/obj/path", new DatabaseAccessImpl());
    } catch (DBusException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
```

where:

DatabaseAccessImpl is implementation of interface created automatically by CreateInterface (xml worked fine while using with c++ (qt)).

dbAccess will send on dbus some data (mostly ints) from database. It all work good in Qt but I have to reimplement it in java (not my language).

For using dbus-java you have to install libmatthew-debug and execute program with

> -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni

I'm working on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1. You need to register a bus name first, i.e. `conn.requestBustName("com.example")`
2. `DatabaseAccessImpl` needs to implement an interface which extends `DBusInterface`.

[Here's](http://rm5248.com/?page_id=76) a tutorial that I made a while ago with code that may help you understand what's going on.

Comment: in this tutorial, where is the so located? and how can I add the ref to the project??